# How to check type of variable in Exception?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I created my own Exception in program but it show error

```
class InvalidTypeException extends Exception {
    InvalidTypeException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
public class CustomException1 {

    static void valid(int a) throws InvalidTypeException {
        if (a instanceof Integer) throw new InvalidTypeException("Valid");
        else System.out.println("Invalid");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            valid(12);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

The compilation error is:

```
src\CustomException1.java:11: error: unexpected type
  if(a instanceof Integer )
     ^
  required: reference
  found:    int
1 error
```

Comment: Please format your code propperly.

Comment: Please tell us what error you have

Comment: @ShrikantHavale *int and Integer are incompatible* -> this is not quite right. This is code is correct and compiles fine: `Integer i = 1; int j = i;`. The actual problem is given in Mureinik's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `instanceof` operator on primitive types, like `a` is currently defined. You could define the argument type as an `Object`:

```
static void valid(Object o) throws InvalidTypeException {
    if (o instanceof Integer) { 
        throw new InvalidTypeException("Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```